# Initializing arrays in VHDL: How exactly does it work?

Tags: arrays, concatenation, vhdl, array-indexing

Consider the following VHDL code:

```vhdl
constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (7 downto 6 => '1', others => '0');
```

Here, the indices 7 and 6 are important: they indicate which elements should be 1, and from that, the compiler can derive which ones should be 0.

**Question 1**

If I understand correctly, this can also be written as

```vhdl
constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (7 downto 6 => '1') & (5 downto 0 => '0');
```

Now I am wondering how exactly this works, and whether the indices still matter or only the difference between them.  The way I understand it, the expression `(x downto y => z)` creates an array with indices `x downto y`, whose elements are all equal to `z` (and have the same type).  But do these indices matter when arrays are concatenated?  I.e., could I also write any of the following:

```vhdl
constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (1 downto 0 => '1') & (5 downto 0 => '0');
constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (99 downto 98 => '1') & (4 downto -1 => '0');
```

Of course one could say that those statements, esp. the last one, aren't really clear, but my question is: Would they have the same result?  Or would they cause some kind or error?

The reason I am wondering about this is that you could also write

```vhdl
constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "11" & "000000";
```

and the literal `"11"` doesn't have any range specified, so I'm not sure what exactly the type of this literal would be, but certainly not `std_logic_vector(7 downto 6)`.

**Question 2**

Finally, I am wondering what is the difference between

```vhdl
constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (7 downto 6 => '1') & (5 downto 0 => '0');
```

and

```vhdl
constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (7 downto 6 => '1', 5 downto 0 => '0');
```

By this I mean: Is there any reason you would want/need to write the former (which seems more error-prone because it will give unexpected results if you e.g. swap the 2 aggregates) instead of the latter?  Or is it just a matter of taste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Lets start with literals. When you specify a literal, the default range is (type_index'low to type_index'low + len-1). The easiest way to see this is when specifying a constant, where the range is not required in the subtype:

```
constant SOME_CONSTANT : std_logic_vector := x"00";
```

Here, if you check the range of SOME_CONSTANT, you'll see its (0 to 7). This is because std_logic_vector is declared as:

```
type std_ulogic_vector is array(natural range <>) of std_logic;
```

The 'low value of natural is 0, which is the start point.

Lets say you went a bit crazy, and this:

```
type my_crazy_array_t is array(std_logic range <>) of integer;
```

and you declared a constant:

```
constant CRAZY : my_crazy_array_t := (0, 22);
```

The results are:

```
CRAZY('U') = 0
CRAZY('X') = 22
CRAZY'left = 'U'
CRAZY'right = 'X'
CRAZY'low = 'U'
CRAZY'high = 'X'
```

Because `'U'` is the low value of `std_logic`, followed by 'X'.

On the other questions, it all works because VHDL is always context driven, and for arrays as long as the lengths match, the resulting arrays can always be mapped from 'left to 'right. In your examples the length is correct, and the subtype is know from the declaration, so mapping can occur as you specified.

NOTE: `(4 downto -1 => '0');` is illegal, because -1 is not a valid index value for a std_logic_vector, so you would get an error (probably from the `&` function because it cannot work out what type you meant, because it cannot be std_logic_vector).

2. The difference is that the first one is a concatenation of a 2 bit and 6 bit bit string, and the 2nd is a complete 8 bit bit string. Which you use will probably be a matter of style. But usually, for this, I would use literals eg: `constant c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"C0";` what you use and when may depend on what is clearest to the user(s).

Comment: Re: 2. above. bit string literals  (IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.8) are lexical elements that have string literal equivalents (15.7). The type of a string literal is taken from context (9.3.2). Unfortunately neither value expressions in Q 2 are bit string literals, the first  a concatenation of two aggregates the second `(7 downto 6 => '1', 5 downto 0 => '0')` an aggregate (9.3.3) with choices expressed as ranges of the aggregate element type (9.3.3.3). An aggregate is an expression with a value produced by a basic operation (5.1). The type is taken from context (9.3.3.1).

Comment: What I meant with question 2 is why would use use a concatenation of aggregates when one single aggregate seems more intuitive and less error-prone (I clarified my question).

Comment: Made an edit. Basically, use what whatever makes most sense in the code at the time.